# API return link instead of Name

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am new in this field, please help.

when i am trying to get value from incident table using servicenow REST API instead of Name in assigned_to field  i get a link. 
how can i get name using REST API. i am using python

> Query

```
url = 'https://comapanyname.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=assignment_group=assignment_group=7a76f60f3d42002
```

> Result

```
'assigned_to': {'link': 'https://companyname.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/0db6ec308f6723a90', 'value': '0db6ec308f6723a90'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get this link because this field is a reference field. That means it does not store the information of the user instead it stores a reference to another record. When you send a GET to the link you will receive the user information.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you want the name of the assignment group, you need to set the parameter **sysparm_display_value** to either "true" or "all" (default is "false"). If you do not want the link, you can set the parameter **sysparm_exclude_reference_link** to "true" (default is "false").

See: https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=madrid&id=r_TableAPI-GET

Comment: Both parameters works perfectly.